# Book by eastern European author about small house toys including a dog called Floki

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I vaguely remember one book from my childhood, which I would be glad to have around. I do not recall much, but I think that it was written by (possibly) Slovenian author, or Slovak. Perhaps even Czech or Polish but that is less likely.

The first part of the book is about small house toys (or animals), where all toys were of the same "species" (e.g. bears), but there is one exception, a small dog called Floki. I think that there is a kid (boy) involved in those stories, and one particular story that I remember is that all the toys gathered and had a race around the apartment. And I also remember that in one story they made cake from carrots (if I haven't mistaken it with some other book).

It is written in the format of several shorter stories.

The second part of the book is about the boy himself, and I think that there is some war involved, and it is more realistic. I remember some duke on a horse marching in (possibly after the war was ended).

Also it was translated into Serbian language. I do not know what is the original language, but i would assume that it is same as authors native language.

Any ideas?

Comment: As per the required information for the Story-id tag 'What language did you read it in, and was it translated?'

Comment: Parts of this sound like [*The Bear Nobody Wanted*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/757880.The_Bear_Nobody_Wanted), but it doesn't match all the details.

Comment: @Spagirl It was translated to Serbian language. This is not very helpful information so i omitted it

Comment: @Randal'Thor That is not the one, sorry

Comment: @Matija when you are looking for a story you can't always tell what others will find relevant to help them identify it. So it is usually better to give *all* the information you have, and certainly all the information required by the tag you have used. if you click on the tag and then click on the [learn more](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) link you will see the additional information abotu the tag, including requirements. In this case, can you edit into your question the language you read the book in and the language it was written in

Comment: Was there also a dog called Fifi? https://goo.gl/images/xE7UMb

Comment: @Spagirl Thank you for clarification, i have added what i know about the language into the questions. And to answer your second comment, i do not recall dog called Fifi, i remember that Floki was unique but accepted and equal into the company.